# using loop to concatenate elements of arrays in Java in a python like way

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to java. I have done python before and concatenating elements of two lists or arrays seemed easy with loop. But how to do the same with java??? For example, I have a multidimensional array:
//codes

```
String [][] nameAry={{"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."},{"Jones","Patel"}};
```

//The output I am expecting :

```
Mr. Jones, Mrs. Jones, Ms, Jones, etc.
```

// I can do it by handpicking elements from indices, as shown in oracle documentation, but what I am looking for is a loop to do the job instead of doing:
//code

```
System.out.println(nameAry[0][0]+", "+nameAry[1][0]);
```

`
////So, is there a way to put it the way I do in python,i.e.,:

```
x=["Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."]
y=["Jonse","patel"]
names-[a+b for a in x for b in y]
```

///this gives me the following result:

```
['Mr.Jonse', 'Mr.patel', 'Mrs.Jonse', 'Mrs.patel', 'Ms.Jonse', 'Ms.patel']
```

//So, is there something like this in Java???

Comment: It's called a cartesian product.

Comment: Just do the same thing as in Python: a for loop executing another for loop. The syntax is different, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I thought so too. But here what I was targeting was to do same thing to a multidimensional array as I did to python lists. I mean, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use loops with index variables to access your array. Here I'm using `i` to loop through the first dimension and `j` for the second dimension of the string array, while assembling each pair and adding it to a list. 
The part with the ArrayList is just for convenience, you can also return the strings or add them to a different data structure. Hope that helps.

Edit: Explanations

```
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String [][] nameAry={{"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."},{"Jones","Patel"}};
        for(int i = 0;i<nameAry[0].length;i++) {
            for(int j =0;j<nameAry[1].length;j++) {
                list.add(nameAry[0][i]+nameAry[1][j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: this is super awesome...!! The method is so easy!!!! I was afraid that I cannot do the with Java what I did with python!! But different dimensions should just be put through different 'for loop' and 'various indices should be marked as different ones'....Excellent ...I love it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: by the way any imports needed?

Comment: Yes you need to import `java.util.ArrayList`. Hope I could answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using streams.

```
String [][] nameAry={{"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."},{"Jones","Patel"}};
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(nameAry[0])
    .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(nameAry[1])
        .map(y -> x + y))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that the `flatMap` method is used here. It is used to turn each element of the first subarray into a new stream. The new stream is created by `.map(y -> x + y)` i.e. concatenating the names to the honorifics. All the new streams are then joined.

Comment: @user7360021 The three imports you need are `java.util.List`, `java.util.Arrays` and `java.util.stream.Collectors`. Also, if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score -1):

I think the use of a 2D array here as **input** is wrong.
You have correctly used 2 arrays as inputs in your Python example.
So just do the same in Java.

Cartesian product method:

```
public String[] cartesianProduct(String[] first, String[] second) {
  String[] result = new String[first.length * second.length];
  int resIndex=0;

  for (int i=0; i < first.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < second.length; j++) {
      result[resIndex] = first[i] + second[j];
      resIndex++;
    }
  }
}
```

Method main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] nameArr = {"Jones","Patel"};
  String[] prefixArr = {"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."};
  String[] result = cartesianProduct(prefixArr, nameArr);

  // Here you can print the result 
}
```